# Where do I find DockerCli.exe

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I'm trying to switch Docker to Windows containers on my Windows Server Core 1903 machine (no desktop). [This](https://forums.docker.com/t/cli-to-switch-between-linux-and-windows-images/30297) page says DockerCli should be able to do so:

```
& $Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

There is no `DockerCli.exe` after fresh Docker installation:

```
    Directory: C:\Program Files\Docker


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       30-09-2019     17:57                cli-plugins
-a----       03-09-2019     21:58       69282136 docker.exe
-a----       03-09-2019     21:58       76065624 dockerd.exe
-a----       21-08-2019     00:05        2454016 libeay32.dll
-a----       11-05-2017     22:32          56978 libwinpthread-1.dll
-a----       03-09-2019     16:24           6124 licenses.txt
-a----       30-09-2019     17:57            142 metadata.json
-a----       21-08-2019     00:05         357888 ssleay32.dll
-a----       09-06-2016     22:53          87888 vcruntime140.dll
```

I also tried to install [docker-cli](https://chocolatey.org/packages/docker-cli) or [docker-toolbox](https://chocolatey.org/packages/docker-toolbox) via Choco but the needed tool is still missing. Any clue where to find it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker command line to switch to running linux containers on Windows Core machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081352/docker-command-line-to-switch-to-running-linux-containers-on-windows-core-machin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found `DockerCli.exe` in the [Docker Desktop](https://chocolatey.org/packages/docker-desktop/2.1.0.3) package.

Comment: Weird. I have Docker Desktop 4.25.0 installed (latest version at this time) and it's still not there.

Comment: I think they got rid of it. I haven't yet found a replacement.  A person on the docker staff [confirmed in the forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/dockercli-exe-options/105673/2) and in [this GH issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/11751) that DockerCLI.exe was apparently an 'internal tool' (?) and 'not meant for end users'.  As far as I'm aware, there is now no longer any way from a command-line/automation to switch between Windows and Linux containers on Windows.

Comment: DockerCLI.exe was added back, but not sure which versions it was removed and added back.