# docker: error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect

Tags: docker, powershell, windows-server-2019, process-isolation

I'm trying to run Docker in process isolation mode on Windows Server 2019 (Docker Desktop does not work here, my VPS does not support Hyper-V).
I run this in PowerShell (all in Administrator mode)
`docker run -it --isolation=process mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 cmd.exe /c ping 127.0.0.1 -t`

Then I get error:

> docker: error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
> See 'docker run --help'.

I ran command `& 'C:\Program Files\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon`, as suggested here: [Docker cannot start on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows)

However, `DockerCli.exe` does not exist in a clean Docker install:
[image]

As [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179462/where-do-i-find-dockercli-exe) I tried copying the file `DockerCli.exe` from my local Windows 10 Docker Desktop installation and reran, but then I get:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Docker.Core, Version=3.0.0.50646, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> at Docker.Cli.MainBackendCli.Run(IReadOnlyCollection`1 args)
> at Docker.Cli.MainBackendCli.Main(String[] args)

Regardless, copying files from Docker Desktop does not feel like the right approach.

I then ran `dockerd` in PowerShell since that's the only other executable in that folder:
[image]

Since I'm a newbie, I'm not sure if I just started a container and if so, which one, I just see `start.`, but no idea where that comes from or how I can configure it.

**UPDATE 1**

Based on Peter Wishart's suggestion I tried `uninstall-Package -Name docker`, but then I get

```
uninstall-Package : No package found for 'docker'. At line:1 char:1
+ uninstall-Package -Name docker
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...ninstallPackage:UninstallPackage) [Uninstall-Package]
   , Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.UninstallPackage
```

Here's the full code of what I tried:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> uninstall-Package -Name docker
uninstall-Package : No package found for 'docker'.
At line:1 char:1
+ uninstall-Package -Name docker
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...ninstallPackage:UninstallPackage) [Uninstall-Package]
   , Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.UninstallPackage

PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker

Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND

A self-sufficient runtime for containers

Options:
      --config string      Location of client config files (default
                           "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.docker")
  -c, --context string     Name of the context to use to connect to the
                           daemon (overrides DOCKER_HOST env var and
                           default context set with "docker context use")
  -D, --debug              Enable debug mode
  -H, --host list          Daemon socket(s) to connect to
  -l, --log-level string   Set the logging level
                           ("debug"|"info"|"warn"|"error"|"fatal")
                           (default "info")
      --tls                Use TLS; implied by --tlsverify
      --tlscacert string   Trust certs signed only by this CA (default
                           "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.docker\\ca.pem")
      --tlscert string     Path to TLS certificate file (default
                           "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.docker\\cert.pem")
      --tlskey string      Path to TLS key file (default
                           "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.docker\\key.pem")
      --tlsverify          Use TLS and verify the remote
  -v, --version            Print version information and quit

Management Commands:
  app*        Docker Application (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)
  builder     Manage builds
  cluster*    Manage Mirantis Container Cloud clusters (Mirantis Inc., v1.9.0)
  config      Manage Docker configs
  container   Manage containers
  context     Manage contexts
  image       Manage images
  manifest    Manage Docker image manifests and manifest lists
  network     Manage networks
  node        Manage Swarm nodes
  plugin      Manage plugins
  registry*   Manage Docker registries (Docker Inc., 0.1.0)
  secret      Manage Docker secrets
  service     Manage services
  stack       Manage Docker stacks
  swarm       Manage Swarm
  system      Manage Docker
  trust       Manage trust on Docker images
  volume      Manage volumes

Commands:
  attach      Attach local standard input, output, and error streams to a running container
  build       Build an image from a Dockerfile
  commit      Create a new image from a container's changes
  cp          Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
  create      Create a new container
  diff        Inspect changes to files or directories on a container's filesystem
  events      Get real time events from the server
  exec        Run a command in a running container
  export      Export a container's filesystem as a tar archive
  history     Show the history of an image
  images      List images
  import      Import the contents from a tarball to create a filesystem image
  info        Display system-wide information
  inspect     Return low-level information on Docker objects
  kill        Kill one or more running containers
  load        Load an image from a tar archive or STDIN
  login       Log in to a Docker registry
  logout      Log out from a Docker registry
  logs        Fetch the logs of a container
  pause       Pause all processes within one or more containers
  port        List port mappings or a specific mapping for the container
  ps          List containers
  pull        Pull an image or a repository from a registry
  push        Push an image or a repository to a registry
  rename      Rename a container
  restart     Restart one or more containers
  rm          Remove one or more containers
  rmi         Remove one or more images
  run         Run a command in a new container
  save        Save one or more images to a tar archive (streamed to STDOUT by default)
  search      Search the Docker Hub for images
  start       Start one or more stopped containers
  stats       Display a live stream of container(s) resource usage statistics
  stop        Stop one or more running containers
  tag         Create a tag TARGET_IMAGE that refers to SOURCE_IMAGE
  top         Display the running processes of a container
  unpause     Unpause all processes within one or more containers
  update      Update configuration of one or more containers
  version     Show the Docker version information
  wait        Block until one or more containers stop, then print their exit codes

Run 'docker COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.

To get more help with docker, check out our guides at https://docs.docker.com/go/guides/
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable

Name                     Version          DynamicOptions
----                     -------          --------------
DockerMsftProvider       1.0.0.8          Update
msi                      3.0.0.0          AdditionalArguments
msu                      3.0.0.0
NuGet                    2.8.5.208        Destination, ExcludeVersion, Scope, SkipDependencies, Headers, FilterOnTag...
PowerShellGet            1.0.0.1          PackageManagementProvider, Type, Scope, AllowClobber, SkipPublisherCheck, ...
Programs                 3.0.0.0          IncludeWindowsInstaller, IncludeSystemComponent


PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Package -Name Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider

Name                           Version          Source                           ProviderName
----                           -------          ------                           ------------
docker                         20.10.0          DockerDefault                    DockerMsftProvider


PS C:\Users\Administrator> Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider

The package(s) come(s) from a package source that is not marked as trusted.
Are you sure you want to install software from 'DockerDefault'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): y
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider

The package(s) come(s) from a package source that is not marked as trusted.
Are you sure you want to install software from 'DockerDefault'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): A
PS C:\Users\Administrator> uninstall-Package -Name docker
WARNING: Docker Service is not available.
uninstall-Package : The property 'Status' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At line:1 char:1
+ uninstall-Package -Name docker
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Microsoft.Power...ninstallPackage:UninstallPackage) [Uninstall-Package],
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.UninstallPackage

PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pipe access that the error message mentions is a (probably unrelated) issue when `docker` client is run by non-admin users (see [here](https://www.axians-infoma.de/techblog/allow-access-to-the-docker-engine-without-admin-rights-on-windows/)).

I think the most likely explanation is that the docker service has failed to start.

When you ran `dockerd` you were actually *starting an instance of the daemon* - and the line `API listen on //./pipe/docker_engine` means that the system service hadn't started previously - as the instance you started could create the pipe.

If you stop the running `dockerd` instance and run:

```
 Get-Service docker | Restart-Service
 Get-WinEvent -logname application | where ProviderName -eq docker | sort TimeCreated
```

You should be able to compare the log output with your manual start of `dockerd`, and see if any errors are blocking the service from starting.

If the event log records `API listen on //./pipe/docker_engine` then `Get-Service docker` should show the service as running, and your `docker` commands should be ok.

[Edit]

Looks like the uninstall of docker was failing because the service doesn't exist.
Yet, the install is succeeding except for the service installation.

You can re-register the service with `&'C:\Program Files\Docker\dockerd.exe' --register-service`

Maybe this will fail if the VPS provider is somehow stopping services from being registered?

Another option is to run docker interactively in one shell with `&'C:\Program Files\Docker\dockerd.exe' --run-service`, and run your docker commands in another shell.

Comment: When I run ` Get-Service docker | Restart-Service` I get error: Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'docker'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Service docker | Restart-Service
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (docker:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand

Comment: Ok, that's not good. The docker installation should have set that up.

Comment: Maybe it's relevant but I never saw docker under services.msc, would it have to be there? If so, is there a way to manually set this up?

Comment: Yes its mandatory. Probably better to uninstall docker (`uninstall-Package -Name docker`) and reinstall.

Comment: I tried that, but that also fails, could you have a look at update 1?

Comment: Have posted an edit with steps to test registering docker as a service (rerun with the correct service name if it succeeds). But I fear you are approaching the point of diminishing return for this system. As a last resort you could run docker interactively and run the docker client in another shell.

Comment: lol, literally started a bounty 1 sec after you replied, I'll try this now :)

Comment: I just edited the instructions to use a built in docker way to fix the service - probably better than using `sc.exe`

Comment: It now works and I see a service `Docker Engine` running, I ended up reinstalling and restarting the VPS a few times. I'll award you the correct answer and bounty as it may help others. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again, if I could make use of your expertise one more time? If you would have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67239760/install-scrapy-on-windows-server-2019-running-in-a-docker-container

Comment: Yes, Docker is not running would give this error. It should have had a self-check as the first step.

Comment: @PeterWishart, you've helped me a lot in the past and was wondering if you could help me again with this post here (I've not been able to work on this project for a few months so still in early stages): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68873134/docker-on-windows-server-2019-failed-to-register-layer-cannot-create-layer-wit

Answer (score 7):

To resolve the issue, I just ran `& 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon` in PowerShell and quit the Docker desktop and Run Docker Desktop as administrator.

Now open command prompt or powershell and run `docker images` or `dockers ps` command. It should work.

Answer (score 4):

Go to PowerShell > run as administrator and run this code:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

Comment: This is basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69243228/6243352).

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i followed 2 steps and my problem was resolved:

1. update wsl kernel, seamingly it is a must because docker needs it and it is not installed by default. so just close all docker realated stuff and run:

```
wsl --update
```

command in cmd .

2. I did what other guys said here:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

and voila!

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to check is whether you have started the Desktop Client for Windows and accepted the License Agreement.  I had restored from an image that hadn't had Docker started and was seeing this error.  Nothing worked until I accepted the license.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, I just ran  Two Steps in PowerShell.

First,

```
cd 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker
```

and then,

```
/DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon
```

After that, install the WSL Kernel on your machine, restart the WSL machine, then it is resolved.

Comment: This is basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69243228/6243352) other than the WSL stuff. Why is it necessary to install/restart WSL?

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5919#issuecomment-658815006

```
cd C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources dockerd.exe
Now execute
'docker version' on a new powershell as administrator
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was removing last edition and installing 4.9.1

Answer (score -2):

I checked these boxes and it worked for me:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Answers should stand on their own, even without images. Some users can't view images.

Comment: What if i don't understand this language? Could you please provide engilsh documentation