# Docker on Windows Server 2019: failed to register layer: Cannot create layer with missing parent

Tags: docker, windows-server-2019

A while back I had installed Docker and created some base images. I noticed a lot of folders were being created in folders `C:\ProgramData\docker\containers` and `C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter`. Besides that I don't know exactly how these folders are different, I wanted to start from scratch, just so I know exactly when and how these folders were created and also to make sure I know how to limit the amount of folders. For that I need a deeper understanding of what happened and how I got here. So I removed all folders from both of the above folders.

Then in PowerShell ran command `docker image pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019` (as described [here](https://blog.sixeyed.com/getting-started-with-docker-on-windows-server-2019/)).

However, then I get error:

```
ltsc2019: Pulling from windows/servercore
4612f6d0b889: Already exists
c67ded6868b6: Extracting [==================================================>]  967.7MB/967.7MB
failed to register layer: Cannot create layer with missing parent b30ce8240c3d9379bedb21d473387a1511327572e7f1721c32ca01b0b1f7fac9: CreateFile C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\b30ce8240c3d9379bedb21d473387a1511327572e7f1721c32ca01b0b1f7fac9: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I Googled that error and checked [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/298).

So I ran `docker images`:

```
REPOSITORY                             TAG        IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
scrapy                                 latest     d6cfd054a887   3 months ago   5.9GB
<none>                                 <none>     edb9e1b2db76   3 months ago   5.27GB
hello-world                            latest     096dec0e4e75   4 months ago   252MB
```

mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore   ltsc2019   152749f71f8f   4 months ago   5.27GB

I'm an absolute newbie to Docker, so which step am I missing above? I basically want to create a completely new Docker image and install Scrapy in it.

PS. I [posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67239760/install-scrapy-on-windows-server-2019-running-in-a-docker-container) on something similar, but am unsure how to start from where I am now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because data for a layer already pulled and extracted (`b30ce824...`) was found to be missing when registering a layer *based* on it. The missing layer data was a `windowsfilter` subfolder with the same 64-character name.

When the `windowsfilter` folder is cleared, you need to also delete the images shown by `docker image ls`. This removes docker's links to the `windowsfilter` cached layers and will let you re-pull new images successfully.

N.B. that the `docker image *` commands are the intended way to manage this folder.

Comment: Thanks. I ran command `docker system prune` as described here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes
Now my entire `containers` folder is emptied and a few folders remain in `windowsfilter`.
Then I ran command `docker image prune -a` and cleared all folders completely, which is perfect, I can now run the pull command successfully once again, thanks!

Comment: Oh, btw, I added an `Update 3` to an older conversation of ours, did not want to start a new question as others would lose all valuable context and it's directly related to the original question. Would you mind having another look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67239760/install-scrapy-on-windows-server-2019-running-in-a-docker-container

Answer (score 3):

For whom use Docker Desktop, open **Troubleshoot** tab (debug icon) in Docker Desktop app, select **Clean/Purge data**, check **Windows Containers** and hit **delete** button as *Simonl65* suggests [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-pull-image-error-failed-to-register-layer/88410/2).