# Change the container OS for docker in Windows Server 2022

Tags: docker, windows-server-2022

We have an install of Windows Server 2022 and want to utilise the built in Docker that comes with it. Is there a way to change the container OS when performing a docker build so that it uses Linux containers.

This is possible in Docker Desktop running on Windows 10 by right clicking the docker icon in the system tray and selecting "switch to windows/linux containers". Is this possible to do in Windows Server 2022?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this, it might for work for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081352/docker-command-line-to-switch-to-running-linux-containers-on-windows-core-machin

Comment: @viggnah: As far as I understand, docker is not running in Docker Desktop but as a Windows-Service in a System-Scope. I don't see a way to run dockercli there, as this only affects docker in User-Scope..

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you're running a recent version of `docker.exe` (v20+):

List all contexts:

```
docker context ls
```

Output:

```
NAME              DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                    
default *         Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine
desktop-linux     Docker Desktop                            npipe:////./pipe/dockerDesktopLinuxEngine
desktop-windows   Docker Desktop                            npipe:////./pipe/dockerDesktopWindowsEngine
```

Change context to desktop-linux:

```
docker context use desktop-linux
```

Output:

```
Current context is now "desktop-linux"
```